# Filter, sort and paginate in sap.m.Table

Tags: sapui5

I want to filter, sort and paginate a **sap.m.Table** that has already been created in the xml. This table has an associated ODataModel. The table is as follows:

```
<Table 
id="tableResults"
items="{
    path: 'PROJECTS>/ZPS_F_PROJECTSLISTSet'
}">
<columns>
    ...
</columns>
<items>
    ...
</items>
```

I get filter the results by doing the following:

```
var aFilter = [];
aFilter.push(new Filter("IdProject", FilterOperator.EQ, "PJ-0100"));
this.byId("tableResults").getBinding("items").filter(aFilter);
```

my question is, can we do something similar to sort and paginate the table?
I tried to do the following:

```
var oSorter = new sap.ui.model.Sorter("IdProject", true); 
this.byId("tableResults").getBinding("items").sorter(oSorter); // KO
this.byId("tableResults").skip(0);  //KO
this.byId("tableResults").top(10);  //KO
```

but these methods do not exist.

I look forward to your answers.

Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are close: Its [sort(oSorter)](https://sapui5.hana.ondemand.com/#docs/api/symbols/sap.ui.model.ListBinding.html#sort) for sorting.

But there are no skip and top methods. Neither [v2](https://sapui5.hana.ondemand.com/#docs/api/symbols/sap.ui.model.odata.v2.ODataListBinding.html#constructor) nor [v4](https://sapui5.hana.ondemand.com/#docs/api/symbols/sap.ui.model.odata.v4.ODataListBinding.html#constructor) of the `ODataModelListBinding` support explicit `$top` and `$skip` query parameters.

A kind of paging is however supported via the [growing](https://sapui5.hana.ondemand.com/#docs/api/symbols/sap.m.ListBase.html#getGrowing) property of the `sap.m.Table`. This is done via `$top` and `$skip` OData query parameters if the ListBinding is in [`server`](https://sapui5.hana.ondemand.com/#docs/api/symbols/sap.ui.model.odata.OperationMode.html#.Server) mode.

Comment: Thank you,

I've seen the solution you've told me but I can not understand how paginate the table through the binding with the "server" mode.

The real problem I have is that I want to create a manual page of the table. To do that I can not use the page "growing" of the table. So he had thought of changing the "ListBinding" to set my own parameters "skip" and "top".

This function is performed by modifying the "ListBinding" always before executing the call:

however I can not change the parameters of range (skip and top), you'd know how to do it?

Comment: In the previous post I have not put the function executed by modifying the "ListBinding" is as follows:   table.getBinding("items").attachDataRequested(function(){  ....  })

Comment: I don't know of an other way then to [create a custom model and binding classes](https://sapui5.hana.ondemand.com/#docs/guide/91f1c7ef6f4d1014b6dd926db0e91070.html) possibly derived from `ODataModel`. An other workaround would be to use a `JSONModel` instead of a `ODataModel`. With that you are free to supply all query parameters you want.